# Why don't we replace d4s with double numbered d8s?

Tags: game-design, dice, accessibility

Maybe this is a dumb or off-topic question, and please see beyond my flippant language: but since dice are such an ingrained part of this hobby...

Recently I got in a fit of nerd-rage at the ungainly d4, and bought some blank d8s from my friendly local game store. A permanent marker and some spots later and I have 3d4 that actually roll...

...Much like the double-number d6s that some companies print for d3s, why isn't an 8-sided d4 simply the standard?

Comment: I don't know, it seems like a matter of basic physics (mechanics) that an 8-sided polyhedron rolls *much* better than a pyramid? Please don't penalize my admittedly flippant language.

Comment: We're not penalising the language. The problem here is that the question is asking “why isn't our reality different?” The only possible answers are speculation or personal theories — hence, the question (and its answers) are primarily a matter of opinion. This would be a fine discussion prompt for a discussion forum — it's not an inherently bad or inappropriate question — but pure opinion/speculation doesn't work on a Q&A site where we have to rank the resulting answers.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:accessibility]? Is there an argument that d8 labeled 1-4 twice would work better for some disabled players?

Comment: @nitsua60 I answered you in chat as well but commenting here for the benefit of others.  Pyramid-shaped d4s are difficult to pick up from a flat surface, even moreso if one lacks fine motor skills.  It remains to be seen if that is  the reason for the tag here, but it certainly *could* apply to the problem.

Comment: I totally see what you're saying, @LegendaryDude. I guess I'd feel better if either the question were edited to explicate the accessibility issue or the tag were removed. (One hope I have for the tag is that one browsing the questions could learn a bit about how to make small, no-cost changes that improve accessibility, even in the absence of a disabled player. This question... doesn't seem to help one understand accessibility in RPGs at all.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There certainly are some rare d8 with two times 1-4 floating around, just like there are more common d20 that have 1-10 twice. However, games like D&D and Pathfinder that use both d4 and d8 or d10 and d20 don't gain a considerable benefit from these, even if they are better to roll:

You buy the better performance at actually rolling with the awkward situation of mixing up the d4/d10 for a d8/d20 or vice versa.

This means possibly wasting a perfect 4/10 on a d4/d10 roll by simply having grabbed a d8/d20 or trying to negotiate a reroll when you realize you rolled the d4/d10 instead of the d8/d20.

Comment: I just painted spots on my blank d8s, so it's easy to see the difference.

My cubic d3s likewise have numbers whereas the d6s have spots...